# how to save user data in cloud firestore using flutter in 2024?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am tryna save each user's data in cloud firestore, searched on stackoverflow, things felt like mixed, as the old solutions are giving errors in 2024, meanwhile am new to beginner, my code below creates a new user on pressing the sign up button, how can i save each user's data as well?

```
 onPressed: () async {
    //show spinner
    //create new account
    try {
      final credential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      print(widget.personIdentity);
      if (widget.personIdentity == 'Student'){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, StudentScreen.id);
      } else {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const DriverScreen(dPersonIdentity: 'Driver'),
        ));
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Map<String,dynamic>` and add the details and then use firestore to store data:

```
Future<void> signUp(String email, String password, String name) async {
  try {
    UserCredential credential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    // this method will be used store data
    Map<String, dynamic> user = {
      'uid': credential.user!.uid.toString(),
      'name': name,
      'email': email
    };

    // this will store user data in USERS collection with docId of UID of the user
    // eg: users/uid/here
    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(credential.user!.uid)
        .set(user); //set method requires a Map<String,dynamic>
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (_) {}
}
```